# ';' expected. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

Can some please help?  I cannot figure out why I am getting this error when I compile this Java file. The error is a tricky one `(';' expected)`. The ";" is expected on line 7 between "New" and "Rectangle" of the test app.

If you need my main app code, I can add that as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RectangleTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        Rectangle rectmeas = New Rectangle(); // LINE 7, WHERE THE ERROR IS
        int userinput = getOptions();
        while ( userinput != 3 )
        {
            switch ( userinput )
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print( "Please enter the length: " );
                    rectmeas.setLen( input.nextDouble() );
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print( "Please enter the width: " );
                    rectmeas.setWid( input.nextDouble() );
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println( rectmeas.toString() );
            userinput = getOptions();
        }
    }
    private static int getOptions()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Press 1 to input the length" );
        System.out.println( "Press 2 to input the width" );
        System.out.print( "Which one?: " );
        return input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: `New` -> `new`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java keywords are all lowercase. You should use `new` instead of `New`.

Answer (score 7):

```
 Rectangle rectmeas = New Rectangle();
```

should be

```
Rectangle rectmeas = new Rectangle();
```

When you want to create an object in java, you need to use `new` instead of `New`. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the advice.  As you have noticed, I am very much a novice.

Answer (score 1):

It's because [all java keyword are lowercase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords), so use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

its new and not New , Java is a case sensitive language and new and New does not mean the same thing. 
new : keyword to create new objects